# How to test if promise returned a correct value or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I want to test if the promise resolved correct value or not, I have written following unit test but I not sure how to proceed further

**file.js**

```
const fs1 = require('fs');

let param ="";
module.exports = {
     test,
     test1
}

function test (outputParam) {
  //module.exports.param = fs1.readFileSync(outputParam);
  (async () => {
    module.exports.param = test1();

  }) ();
}

function test1 () {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    let promiseVar = "success";
    resolve(promiseVar);
  })
}
```

**file.spec.js**

```
let sinon = require("sinon");
let filejs = require('./file.js');
const fs = require('fs');
let expect = require('chai').expect;

it('should stub a promise ' ,function() {

  let someArg ="file.xml";

  filejs.test(someArg);
  expect(filejs.param).to.equal('success');
 })
```

When I run the test I see

> AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'failure'

Comment: Remember that if you're working with code that uses `async` or Promises, you want to manually say the test is done, rather than the testing being considered "done" simply by reaching the end of the top level test function. https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stub a promise such that it always resolves a particular value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306699/how-to-stub-a-promise-such-that-it-always-resolves-a-particular-value)

Comment: Are you double posting questions?

Comment: Hi I had two different questions , I believe both tests would look different

Comment: we couldn't do `module.exports.param` inside the function like that I believe. When we include `file.js` in the test file, it will just contains two exports.